# How to make "Add to clipboard" functionality in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How do I achieve **add to clipboard** functionality in asp.net web site, if I have to copy text in textbox or label. Please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement this with JavaScript, as copying to the user's clipboard has to be done on the client machine and not on the server. See this post:

[How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)